# Exception thrown with adsense on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, adsense

I've copied and pasted inside my HTML  tag the adsense javascript code google hands out -

```
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:inline-block;width:234px;height:60px"
             data-ad-test="on"
             data-ad-client="XXXXX"                  
             data-ad-slot="XXXXX"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
```

[I replaced the actual data-ad-client and data-ad-slot values with XXX when pasting the code here]

It works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Edge but on Internet Explorer i'm getting an exception thrown. It's saying "Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getRandomValues'of undefined or null reference' on the r.crypto.getRandomValues(d); function call within adsense script.

No clue what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't manage to fully get around it, but i set visual studio to not bother with that exception and everything worked just fine. Eventually switched to DFP so this is no longer an issue if anyone still care.

Answer (score 0):

You code be emulating an older version of IE.

You can test for the latest crypto using this script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Web Cryptography API</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

    var crypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;

    if (crypto) {
      console.log(crypto);
      
    } else {
      console.log("Unable to create window.crypto object");
    } 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check the mode you are running in developer tools:

[image]

Comment: Worked fine on my machine. No issues. Not sure if the issue is the crypto API or something else that's triggering it.